# (graph-tool) how to get the value from property map as an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-tool

First, I'm newbie on python.

This is my code to get centrality betweenness using graph-tool module on python3

```
vertex_betweenness = betweenness(g)
```

then after I got a property map which contains the value I want.

I have tried this

```
for v in g.vertices():
   print(vertex_betweenness[v])
```

I have tried to output it in some ways, print to the screen or create csv file but I cannot do it. I think I don't know about how to iterate through that property map.

I already googled for a few days but no pages can help me solve this question.

Answer (score 2):

The function `betweenness()` returns **two** property maps, for both vertex and edge property maps (see the documentation at https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/centrality.html#graph_tool.centrality.betweenness). Your snipped will work if you modify it to

```
vertex_betweenness, edge_betweenness = betweenness(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the docs, you can get the scalar values from a property map using the .get_array() method or .a. Seems to be the easiest way for me!